# Setting up alert on system load average for a Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I am working with a spring boot application, which is deployed on 3 Kubernetes pods.

I have set up an alert on `system.load.average` coming from the Spring boot actuator. In this regard, I have set up the threshold as 3.0. But I am seeing the value > 3.0 sometimes, that's why I am getting alerts.

I am not able to understand, how I am receiving a value > 3.0, maybe I am doing something wrong here.

Could anyone please help here ? Thanks.

Comment: You will  have to provide more details. This question is very ambiguous.

Comment: are you wondering if it's possible to have LA > 3? Answer is yes, it's totally possible.

Comment: @VasiliAngapov Could you please explain why?